# storing multiple connection string in xml file asp.net

Tags: connection-string

Based on company and unit selected by user i have to select connection string. I want to know what is the best practice to store multiple connection string. Should i store it in XML file or web.config file? or at any other place.

Thank you very much

Comment: seems very similiar (though less detailed) to the previous question you asked yesterday (now apparently deleted/closed)

Comment: if you have multiple databases per company plus site, you are likely going to have a high maintenance cost.

Comment: I am making project for the company which has same site but multiple units where work is done. On Unit Selection I have to get connection string. using asp.net with sql server 2005

Comment: @Mohan Sharma: I understand what you are trying to do. I am trying to tell you that your approach might have drawbacks...

Answer (score 0):

We have some legacy systems that run different databases, than our "official" system.
I have always stored the different connection strings in the webconfig, and selected the one I need, in my code.

```
ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PDM"].ConnectionString;
```

Personally, I would keep it all in web.config.